# Java, nested class: how to access 'higher' level variable?

Tags: java

i've this code

```
public class MasterClass {

    private String myVariable;
    private ValuesClass objectA;

        class ValuesClass {

              public void method() {
                   myVariable = 1; // I can't access myVariable
              }
        }

}
```

How to access myVariable  from inside ValuesClass ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are doing is exactly correct. Except that `myVariable` is a `String`, and you are trying to assign an `int` to it.

Now, if your inner class ALSO had a variable called `myVariable`, you would need some special syntax to access the one from the *outer* class:

```
MasterClass.this.myVariable = ...
```

**Edit by Martijn:** This is called a [Qualified This](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4).

Comment: I felt free to add the technical name of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it directly with `myVariable`, or if you have conflicting variable names,

```
public class MasterClass {

private String myVariable;
private ValuesClass objectA;

    class ValuesClass {
          private String myVariable
          public void method() {
               MasterClass.this.myVariable = "Hello World!";
          }
    }
```

}